# Скрытое boolean поле в дата-классе

Tags: kotlin, сериализация, dataclass

Столкнулся с неявным поведением кода Kotlin. В data классе объявлен метод с названием isChanged. Очевидно, из-за названия, начинающегося с "is", при сериализации в базу данных сохраняется несуществующее Boolean-поле Changed, и при десериализации Json ObjectMapper падает с ошибкой:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
> Unrecognized field "changed" (class ...), not marked as ignorable

Изменение data class на обычный class не дает результатов. Предполагаю, `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` может помочь, но это выглядит как явный костыль. В итоге сработало очевидное решение с изменением имени метода, но хотелось бы разобраться, почему такое происходит и как это элегантно обойти.

Comment: Jackson думает что это getter для read-only поля. Добавьте аннотацию `@JsonIgnore` к методу и Jackson будет его пропускать при сериализации. Вам ведь это надо?

Comment: Помогло. Спасибо!